# Google map client side(Google Maps JavaScript API) geocoding keep counting quota of all session?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API to load and search(geocoding) locations on map. As google suggests to use API key, I'm using the API key in my site so i can monitor the requests too.

Also google [says](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client);

> Client-side geocoding will not face a quota limit unless you perform a
>   batch of geocoding requests within a user session. Therefore, running
>   client-side geocoding, you generally don't have to worry about your
>   quota.

But when I check the usage via Google Developer console, the request keep counting even i'm accessing and searching the location from different browsers(sessions). it seems that Google count all sessions geocoding requests into one place. is that mean, I get quota limit when it reaches 2500? or no need to warry about it as google says "you generally don't have to worry about your quota." or am I missing something?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client)-> Quota Considerations

*Client-side geocoding through the browser is rate limited per map session, 
so the geocoding is distributed across all your users and scales with your userbase. Geocoding quotas and rate limits drive the strategies outlined in this article.*

And  from Quota summary

```
 Daily quota resets at midnight Pacific Time (PT).
 Free quota    2,500 requests/day
 Total quota   2,500 requests/day
 Remaining     2,500 requests/day      100% of total
```

I desume you can use free only 2500 geocoding /day

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge for the quick reply. but what is see here is, the rate limitation is something like 10 request/sec per map session for all user session. 
And in the same Geocoding Strategies page google says "Client-side geocoding will not face a quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a user session". But server side geocoding has 2,500 requests/day.